# How to set background image with array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the background with an image from an array of objects....I have an array of objects like this:

```
const cars= [
  {name: "Toyota", image: "toyota.jpg"},  
  {name: "Ford", image: "ford.jpg"}
];
```

and I want to get the Toyota image, i.e. : `console.log(cars[0].image);`
...so I tried creating a variable:   `let imageSource = car[0].image;`

`document.body.style.backgroundImage = imageSource;`   //not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the image in `url()`:

```js
const cars = [
  {name: "Toyota", image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300?1"},  
  {name: "Ford", image: "https://picsum.photos/200/300?1"}
];

const imageSource = `url(${cars[0].image})`;

document.body.style.backgroundImage = imageSource;
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help :)